# In meteor js, how can I make sure a CSS file will override anithing else for a specific template?

Tags: meteor

I read posts about meteor file loading order.

But if I wish to make sure a CSS snippet will override any other CSS (loaded later for another template) How can I make sure the CSS snippet has final word for a template?

(put it in a top folder non lib would anyway load it before the following templates. And using another template, the problem will be the same from the POV of that other template)

Some people suggest, and I like it, to have a CSS file for each template, so we know what CSS is used for that template and we do not build a big large CSS, even if, meteor consolidate them.

Comment: `!important` (_runs away_)

Answer (score 0):

I like the convention of adding a unique class name to each template. Here's an example:

```html
<template name="posts">
  <div class="__posts">
    {{#each posts}}
      <p>{{text}}</P>
    {{/each}}
  </div>
</template>
```

Then in your css you can specifically target instances of the `posts` template like this:

```html
.__posts p {
  color: blue;
}
```

You don't, of course, have to use the double-underscore but I find that makes a convenient indicator that the class is unique to a template. Also note this technique solves another common problem: how to identify which template rendered which portion of the current DOM.

Comment: Do you intend to use this class more than once? If so you may want to make it appear in your code, otherwise an id would work just fine.

Comment: You remind me an essential tool that are classes and ID for CSS, thanks, but many frameworks and packages - such as bootstrap - and our own IU logic need many classes. How can we make sure a class is "defined" last so its CSS overrides the others? Do we just need to teclare it last in class list in the div block? Thanks

Comment: A precondition for understanding my answer is to know how [css specificity](https://www.google.com/search?q=css+specificity) works. By using greater specificity in your css, you can easily target a particular element without needing to worry about load order.